# Confusion about UserManager in identity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am currently working on a Web API that will be used to build an ASP.Net MVC project. I am used to using Membership and the entity framework.

We have decided to use the Identity framework for managing the users. I have a loose understanding of the UserManager and UserStore. My problem is that I cannot work out how to get a reference to the UserManager object. The reason I want this is so that I can test if a user is locked. Do i need to implement a custom UserManager to achieve this functionality? I was under the impression the default UserManager can achieve this?

Comment: What version of Identity are you going to use (currently 1 and 2 exist as of this writing)?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I cannot work out how to get a reference to the UserManager object.

If you are using all the default implementations with OWIN and Identity 2.0, then you simply call:

```
var userManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current
  .GetOwinContext()
  .GetUserManager<MyApplicationUserManager>();
  // where MyApplicationUserManager is your derived type
```

Then you need access to the User to get the Id:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

And call the either method:

```
var isLockedOut = await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(userId);
```

or the [non-async extension method version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions(v=vs.108).aspx):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
var isLockedOut = userManager.IsLockedOut(userId);
```